# React fetch works in one app, "Failed to Fetch" in another

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I've got a boiler-plate Visual Studio React JS app.  The one that comes from the VS wizard and gives you the ASP.NET  "Weather Forecast" Controller.   Naturally the client React JS app's call to fetch works just fine with no issues.

I also have a completely separate, functional standalone React JS app that I want to adapt to call this server.  So I took my little fetch call from the MS-generated app and copied it into the standalone app

```
fetch("https://localhost:44439/weatherforecast");
```

Then I debugged the standalone app in Visual Studio Code.

The fetch *does* reach my MS generated "Weather Forecast" controller, just as it does with the MS-generated app.  And my controller returns the same canned data, just as it does with the other app.

But then in my standalone app, I get an error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Why would the exact same call work in one app and not in another when it actually reaches the server?  And how do I diagnose what's going wrong?  This isn't a very helpful error message.